# Data frames containing tuples

Tags: r, dataframe, genetic-algorithm

I'm working on a GA algorithm (for a combinatorics problem) in in which genes are easiest to work with when represented by tuples. Each member of my population with have multiple genes, so I want a data frame to that can hold observations where there are a few atomic variables (e.g. an ID and a score) and then some of the variables represent tuples. I've tried represent those tuples using vectors, lists, and matrices but in all cases R is simply `cbind`/`rbind`ing the tuples into the data frame or throwing an error.

Example (start both members of the population with same genes)

```
ID<-1:2
Score<-c(0,0)
Gene1<-list(1:3)
Gene2<-list(4:6)
Gene3<-list(7:9)
testing<-data.frame(ID,Score,replicate(2,Gene1),replicate(2,Gene2),replicate(2,Gene3))
Error in data.frame(ID, Score, replicate(2, Gene1), replicate(2, Gene2),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 3
```

I want the data frame to look like this...

[image]

And I would then be able to score fitness of a population member using something like `Fitness.Score(testing[,'Gene1'],testing[,'Gene2'],testing[,'Gene3'])`

Is there a way to make R do this?

Comment: I don't think R data frames are capable of storing lists objects in a cell like that. You're probably going to have to rethink how you combine the data.

Comment: You could store the population as a list of lists; the inner lists would contain the ID, score, and genes.

Comment: or store each cell as a string and add an extra line to split the `'1,2,3'` into something you can work with

Comment: If you really want list columns, you can wrap them in `I()`, like this: `data.frame(ID, Score, Gene1 = I(replicate(2,Gene1)))`. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually way easier to do than I was making it. Using the `data.frame` function causes the `rbind`/`cbind` type behavior. Creating a data.frame and then adding the variables afterward does not.

```
ID<-1:2
Score<-c(0,0)
Gene1<-list(1:3)
Gene2<-list(4:6)
Gene3<-list(7:9)
testing<-data.frame(ID,Score)
testing$Gene1<-replicate(2,Gene1)
testing$Gene2<-replicate(2,Gene2)
testing$Gene3<-replicate(2,Gene3)
View(testing)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should download the package 'sets' and then declare your variables that contain tuples as.tuples: mydata$variable<-as.tuples( In your dataframe, you can then have entries such as (1,2,4) for a 3-tuple.